# Status Bar Not Updating In Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a piggy game and when the piggy kills everyone I want the status GUI to say "The piggy has killed everyone". I have four different outcomes and only this one doesn't work. Here is the link to the rest of my code.

https://pastebin.com/zkHEgqjQ

```
if #contestents == 0 then
   outcome = "piggy-killed-everyone"
   break
end
```

If anyone could help that would be awesome!

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your question to be more focused.

Comment: Did you go to pastebin?